# Showing statistics from Google Analytics on your site without login

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a web site where people can search for data. I want to show a list of the most popular searches on the site. Today I'm storing all searches using Google Analytics. It looks like this: `window._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'search', q, 'us']);`

Here q is the search term and 'us' the market.

Is it possible to  get the most popular searches preferably for each market? I want to do it using JavaScript and possibly a php proxy that "login" to Google Analytics and I don't want the visitors to login or approve any apps before.

Comment: Have you looked at the Google Analytics API? You'll probably want to do this serverside and offer a temporarily cached version to JavaScript.

Comment: I've google around for awhile but haven't ant good resources. My server side skills are limited so that's why I'm looking for a JavaScript solution first. If there are any.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in JavaScript without giving away your user credentials, and still you'd be talking to Google's Analytics API. I find it hard to believe you can't find any good resources because it's right here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference

And here is a library (in your favorite language): https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataLibraries

Comment: Thanks! I'll loo into this :) The problem was not to find any. The problem was that is was to much information.